# How can i make strings contain the delimiter after tokenizing?

Tags: c

I just started studying C language on Ubuntu i've been trying to make a simple Shell which just works a little like a shell. So, right after i get the command line i guess i might have to split the line with a delimiter. firstly I wanna tokenize the string with '&' delim containing the delimiter using "strtok_r()", but "strcat()" somehow doesn't work through what i wanted

i tried using "strcat()" after making tokens. if i use the function, the first token's output works well with the second tokens, however, thrown away.

the output is simply like this. lets say i have these tokens.

```
token1 : abcde
token2 : fghij
```

and then if i use "strcat('&')"  with this, its out put is like

```
token1 : abcde&
token2 : &
```

i think this might be becuase the delimiter that i'm trying to put at the end of "token1" affects to the adrress for "token2".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
        static const char delim[] = "&";

        char str[256] = "sleep 5 & echo Hello & sleep 5; echo Hello";

        char *args[50];

        char *save;
        char *pBuf;
        int i = 0;

        for(pBuf = strtok_r(str, delim, &save);
                        pBuf;
                        pBuf = strtok_r(NULL, delim, &save)){

                printf("%d\n", i);
                args[i++] = pBuf;

        }


        /** OUT PUT START*/

        i = 0;

        while(args[i]){
                printf("args[%d] : %s\n", i , args[i]);
                i++;
        }

        /**OUT PUT END  */

        return 0;
}
```

---

---

```
********OUT PUT

args[0] : sleep 5
args[1] :  echo Hello
args[2] :  sleep 5; echo Hello

********EXPECTED OUT PUT

args[0] : sleep 5 &
args[1] : echo Hello &
args[2] : sleep 5; echo Hello
```

Comment: You have to carefully study manuals. [strtok_r](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) substitutes the delimeter with a null termination byte. It does not "remove leading spaces" or "return copies of the string". It works on `str` memory, no other memory is being used. There is no memory to put `&` in the string. You need to allocate memory for your needs, remove leading spaces by hand, add the delimeter to the end and remember to free the allocated memory.

Comment: Also `char *args[50];` is not initialized, so it has "indeterminate" values, not NULL. Your "OUT PUT" part has undefined behavior - `while(args[i])` may be true while `args[i]` being an invalid pointer.

Comment: Do you mean if char *pBuf is Null at the first time, args[i] could possibly not initialized?

Comment: Will it be intialized if it's the second time? The third time? It will not. Only the first n values will be initiliazed. For example you code does seg fault [here](https://onlinegdb.com/S1hsvaBcN), because the `args[i]` is not intialized. Initialize it - add `char *args[50] = {0};`

Answer (score 2):

The question is what good `strtok` does in this case. Instead of complicating things you can just do the parsing manually with `strchr`. Soon as you find the delimiter `&`, you can expect a trailing space and print that space and the end, not the beginning. Example:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  const char str[256] = "sleep 5 & echo Hello & sleep 5; echo Hello";
  size_t length = strlen(str);

  const char* s1 = str;
  const char* s2;
  const char delim = '&';

  while(s1 < str+length)
  {
    s2 = strchr(s1, delim);
    if(s2 == NULL)
    {
      s2 = &str[length]; // point at null term
    }
    else
    {
      s2++; // point at space
    }
    printf("%.*s\n", s2-s1, s1); // print (s2-s1) characters
    s1 = s2+1; // point at next char after space, or 1 past null term
  }
}
```

Output:

```
sleep 5 &
echo Hello &
sleep 5; echo Hello
```

(Note that it is fine in C to point 1 item past the end of the array, but not to de-reference that address.)